# Should I use thekernel graphics diveror the xserver-xorg-video-intel driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

What is the advantage of one over the other?

I'm currently using i915 kernel module, but my display is dull, would I gain anything if I switch to the xorg driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little bit of confusion going on:

- the `i915` module is a kernel module/driver for your iGPU, there are no alternatives to it
- `xorg-x11-drv-intel` is what required for `X.org` to communicate with your kernel driver, it's basically a "driver" for the `X.org` server.

> my display is dull

I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.